# Metamask with React

Tags: web3js, metamask

I currently have my app set up with testrpc and I'm trying to set the current provider to Rinkeby (or whatever testnet I'm on in MetaMask). However, when I run the following code, nothing shows up. I'm calling initWeb3 in my componentWillMount.

```
initWeb3() {
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit old question, however, if someone came up with the issue, you need to init it with load event.

```
componentWillMount() {
   window.addEventListener('load', this.initWeb3)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('load', this.initWeb3)
}
```